# How to get the mean and median of a table in R?

Tags: r

I have the following table, `tab1`:

```
25  26  27  28  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  48  49  50  52 
 9   3   2  17 214   1  52  19  17 894  30   5  91   4 588   1  20   1   3  49   2   1   2  12   1
```

I tried `summary(tab1)` thinking it would give me the minimum, maximum, median, mean, etc. but it didn't work.

I tried simple operations like `mean(tab1)`, but it gives me the wrong result (way higher than 52). For context, the first line of my table is ages and the second line is frequencies. I would like an easy way to get the mean and median age.

I've seen a comment asking to do `dput(tab1)`, so here is what I get when I do that :

```
structure(c(`25` = 9L, `26` = 3L, `27` = 2L, `28` = 17L, `30` = 214L, 
`31` = 1L, `32` = 52L, `33` = 19L, `34` = 17L, `35` = 894L, `36` = 30L, 
`37` = 5L, `38` = 91L, `39` = 4L, `40` = 588L, `41` = 1L, `42` = 20L, 
`43` = 1L, `44` = 3L, `45` = 49L, `46` = 2L, `48` = 1L, `49` = 2L, 
`50` = 12L, `52` = 1L), dim = 25L, dimnames = structure(list(
    c("25", "26", "27", "28", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
    "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", 
    "46", "48", "49", "50", "52")), names = ""), class = "table")
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome! Can you run `dput(tab1)`,  edit the post and copy-paste the output in your question? It helps us understand the format for your summary table/your data

Comment: It's probably simpler to perform summary statistics using the raw data from which the table was derived. Presumably you used a vector of values, or a column from a data frame, to generate the table?

Comment: @neilfws Yes initially I used the summary function directly by selecting the column from the database but then I wanted to exclude two values that were not ages in order to get a more accurate summary, so that's how I ended up with a table.

Comment: If you can show us some example original data (again using `dput`), we can advise as to how unwanted values can be excluded.

Comment: @neilfws I tried using dput but it just gave me a way too long list of numbers followed by L, like `c(40L, 30L, ...)`, I don't know if it's useful sorry

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the function `weighted.mean`:

```
weighted.mean(as.numeric(names(tab1)), tab1)
[1] 36.30667

summary(as.numeric(rep(names(tab1), tab1)))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  25.00   35.00   35.00   36.31   40.00   52.00
```

---

You could also use `uncount`:

```
as.data.frame(tab1)|>
    tidyr::uncount(Freq) %>%
    type.convert(as.is=TRUE) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(mean = mean(Var1), median = median(Var1))

      mean median
1 36.30667     35
```

Answer (score 1):

For `mean`, you can try

```
> c(crossprod(proportions(tab1), as.numeric(names(tab1))))
[1] 36.30667
```

and for median you can use `median` directly, or

```
> fivenum(rep(as.numeric(names(tab1)), tab1))[3]
[1] 35
```

## Data

```
> dput(tab1)
c(`25` = 9L, `26` = 3L, `27` = 2L, `28` = 17L, `30` = 214L, `31` = 1L, 
`32` = 52L, `33` = 19L, `34` = 17L, `35` = 894L, `36` = 30L,
`37` = 5L, `38` = 91L, `39` = 4L, `40` = 588L, `41` = 1L, `42` = 20L,
`43` = 1L, `44` = 3L, `45` = 49L, `46` = 2L, `48` = 1L, `49` = 2L,
`50` = 12L, `52` = 1L)
```